# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Client Computer Files over the network

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, windows-networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I just setup an office computer server running windows server 2012 R2 and I already installed Active Directory, DHCP and DNS. And also I added a client computers to my server and created users account.

My problem is, the client computer has a previous files of my employee and I still want him to access those files using user account I created.

But everytime He login in the client computer using user account I created, all the previous files of that computer are hidden. Basically, he has no access to the files that were stored in that computer.

Anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use that user to take ownership of said files. Right click directory, Permissions, advanced... Look for the owner tab. Change the owner to the new appropriate owner.

Some info on ownership: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779180(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Should I need to do this to each client computer? I have 30 computers here in my office. What if I add new computers?

Comment: I think its hassle if I will do it one by one. Is there anything else to do this using my server?

Comment: Your files are probably stored on NTFS file system. This means their permissions area carried "with" them.... and not the Operating system. You need to "change" their permissions, that was aimed at accounts on the previous server, to reflect permissions/accounts on the new server. New files created, will have the correct permission, but the old files, will have to be re-"permissioned" ..<- if that's even a word.

Comment: See this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779180(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Can I change ownership in windows server 2012?